# React Native View and Flex: 1 not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I learning React Native and I'm doing a simple View and setting the style to a container style, but nothing happens when I run the code.  The View is now filling with the color read from the code.  Its very starter code, just not seeing where its going wrong?  When I run this, nothing in the view changes, it just white?  I was expecting to see a screen of red?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import SLSHeader from '../app-components/slsheader';

export default function Home (props) {
    return (
        <View styles={styles.container}>
            
        </View>
    );  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi can You share the component code where you are using "Home' component

Comment: try css as  ```container:{height:"100%",backgroundColor:"red"}```

Answer (score 0):

The only place Im using it thus far is in a Navigator file...  Its a switch Navigator with a Drawer Navigator...

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

//import CustomDrawer from './CustomDrawer';

//Import Screens
import LoginScreen from '../screens/Login';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/Home';

//Drawer Screens
const DrawerScreens = {
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            headerShown: false
        }
    }
}

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(DrawerScreens, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            height: 60
        }
    },
    //contentComponent: CustomDrawer
});


//Pre Login Screens
const PreLoginScreens = {
    Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            headerShown: false
        }
    },
    PostLogin: {
        screen: DrawerNavigator
    }
}

const PreloginNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(PreLoginScreens,{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {}
});

export default createAppContainer(PreloginNavigator);
```

Comment: Where you can using this appContainer?  I am assuming in the App.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import SLSNavigator from './Navigation/SLSNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SLSNavigator />
  );
}
```